# How to include external library in C++?

Tags: c++, macos

I am trying to include an [external library called SVL (simple vector library)](https://github.com/jyunming-chen/svl-1.5) into c++. I am having a lot of trouble with this. I am using Mac OSX and the `README`for the library has tutorial only for Windows.

I did

```
 make clean
 make
```

This created the library files `libsvl.a`and `libsvl.dbg.a`. I see that in [`README`of the file](https://github.com/jyunming-chen/svl-1.5), it says to include it as `svl/vec3.h`or so for different headers. But when I try to do this, it does not work and still says,

```
vertex.hh:9:10: fatal error: 'svl/Vec3.h' file not found
#include <svl/Vec3.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
vertex.cc:10:10: fatal error: 'svl/Vec3.h' file not found
#include <svl/Vec3.h>
```

Can you suggest me what am I missing? I may need to define path to library better or do something different.

The relative path of library files from the other codes is `../svl-1.5/lib/libsvl.a`

make config file

```
#

# Mac OSX

#
CONFIG = OSX

# --- Compilation
----------------------------------------------------------
CC          =   cc
CXX         =   c++
LD          =   c++
MAKEDEP     =   c++ -MM $(SYS_INC_DIRS) $(INC_DIRS) $(SRCS) >     Makefile.depend
CPP         =   cpp
LIBTOOL     =   glibtool

LD_FLAGS    =
CFLAGS      =   -O2
DBG_CFLAGS  =   -g

SHARED_LIBS = off
USE_RANLIB = 1    

DEST        =   $(REACTOR)

config:
    @echo "configured for Mac OSX"

# --- System     -------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_INC_DIRS        =  -I/sw/include
SYS_LIB_DIRS        =  -L/sw/lib
SYS_LIBS            =
SYS_DBG_LIBS        =

# --- VL     -----------------------------------------------------------------------
CL_EXT_FLAGS = -DCL_TMPL_INST -DCL_HAS_VSNPRINTF -DCL_POSIX_TIME
VL_EXT_FLAGS = -DVL_HAS_ABSF -DVL_USE_MEMCPY
```

result of running `make`

```
cd src && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make REACTOR=..
c++  -O2   \
            -c LibSVL.cpp -I../include -I/sw/include
c++  -O2   \
            -c Basics.cpp -I../include -I/sw/include
ar rcu libsvl.a LibSVL.o Basics.o
mkdir -p ../lib
mv libsvl.a ../lib
c++ -DDEBUG  -g  \
            -DVL_DEBUG \
            -c LibSVL.cpp -o LibSVL.do -I../include -I/sw/include
c++ -DDEBUG  -g  \
            -DVL_DEBUG \
            -c Basics.cpp -o Basics.do -I../include -I/sw/include
```

Complete `make`file

```
#
# Main makefile for SVL distribution
#

# NOTE: To build multiple system libraries in AFS, make 'afs-setup' first.
# This will create the necessary architecture-dependent lib directories,
# and ensure that the config header goes there.

REACTOR=.

all: $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config.mf
    cd src && $(MAKE) REACTOR=..

SHELL           = /bin/sh
DEST            = /usr/local
CONFIG_DEST     = $(DEST)/include

clean:  
    @-echo 'Making clean...'
    @-cd src && $(MAKE) REACTOR=.. clean
    @-rm -f lib/lib*

install: install-headers install-libs

install-headers:
    @-echo "installing into $(DEST)/include/svl $(DEST)/doc"
    @-chmod a+r include/svl/* doc/*
    @-umask 022 \
        && mkdir -p $(DEST)/doc $(DEST)/include/svl
    @-umask 022 \
        && cp doc/* $(DEST)/doc \
        && cp include/svl/* $(DEST)/include/svl
    @-echo "done."

install-libs:
    @-echo "installing into $(DEST)/lib $(CONFIG_DEST)"
    @-chmod a+r lib/* include/SVLConfig.h
    @-umask 022 \
        && mkdir -p $(DEST)/lib $(CONFIG_DEST)
    @-umask 022 \
        && cp lib/* $(DEST)/lib \
        && cp include/SVLConfig.h $(CONFIG_DEST)
    @-echo "done."

# setup for multi-architecture build in afs.
afs-setup:
    @-echo "Creating afs multiple-system lib directory"
    @-rm -r lib; ln -s .arch/@sys/lib lib
    # ensure the config file goes in the lib directory.
    @-ln -sf ../lib/svl/SVLConfig.h include/SVLConfig.h

# if lib is a broken symbolic link, create the necessary .arch directory.
afs-lib:
    @-if test ! -d lib; then mkdir -p .arch/`sys`/lib/svl; \
       touch .arch/`sys`/lib/svl/SVLConfig.h; fi

config: afs-lib
    $(MAKE) config -f makefiles/svl.mf

# --- setup -----------

# auto-generated by make-config-mf

$(REACTOR)/makefiles/config.mf:
    @-echo "=== System Configuration ==="
    @-echo "Select one of the following systems, and then run 'make <system>'."
    @-echo 
    @-echo "    OSX"
    @-echo "    alpha"
    @-echo "    linux_RH"
    @-echo "    sgi-n32"
    @-echo "    sgi-n64"
    @-echo "    sgi-o32"
    @-echo "    solaris-gcc"
    @-echo "    sunos-gcc"
    @-echo 
    @-echo "After this is done, you can edit makefiles/config.mf to change"
    @-echo "compiler settings and paths. If you change the build flags, you"
    @-echo "must run 'make config' to update the headers."
    @exit 1

OSX:
    cp $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config-OSX.mf $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config.mf
    $(MAKE) config
alpha:
    cp $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config-alpha.mf $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config.mf
    $(MAKE) config
linux_RH:
    cp $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config-linux_RH.mf $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config.mf
    $(MAKE) config
sgi-n32:
    cp $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config-sgi-n32.mf $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config.mf
    $(MAKE) config
sgi-n64:
    cp $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config-sgi-n64.mf $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config.mf
    $(MAKE) config
sgi-o32:
    cp $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config-sgi-o32.mf $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config.mf
    $(MAKE) config
solaris-gcc:
    cp $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config-solaris-gcc.mf $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config.mf
    $(MAKE) config
sunos-gcc:
    cp $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config-sunos-gcc.mf $(REACTOR)/makefiles/config.mf
    $(MAKE) config
```

Comment: Don't repost questions.  [Original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131667/including-an-external-library-in-c-program-using-mac-osx).

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: Great!! that helped. There error is gone with `#include` and it says 
`In file included from vertex.cc:10:`
`In file included from /usr/local/include/svl/Vec3.h:14:`  
 but now I have other errors that says `error: unknown type name 'Real'` so classes are not linked properly, i guess.  i am just doing `g++ vertex.cc vertex.hh` for compiling. Should I include some other instruction in compiling?